# How can I convert Arabic Unicode

Tags: python, encoding, python-2.7

I'm working on Arabic light stemmer package in python
I want to convert the result from any operation from Unicode to Arabic letters.

My code:

```
import tashaphyne
form tashaphyne  import *
>>> text = u"الْعَرَبِيّةُ"
>>> strip_tashkeel(text)
```

I want it to display "العربية" not it's Unicode

Comment: Displaying the Arabic correctly in the terminal can depend on the types of encoding your terminal supports. The general principle is that you need to encode the Unicode to a particular encoding, e.g. UTF-8. Code sample: `print text.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: see http://pyright.blogspot.ie/2009/08/unicode-arabic.html

Comment: Just a note that the code sample on that website is in Python 3 which may be confusing as Unicode is handled differently in 3.x compared to how it is handled in 2.x

Answer (score 1):

You can convert unicode strings to any other encoding using the encode() function like so:

```
text.encode('utf8')
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) is a list of possible encodings in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You see `u'\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629'` instead of "العربية" because `repr()` representation for unicode strings is meant to be displayable even on 7-bit terminals.

To see actual scripts instead of unicode, do either `print _` after your call to `strip_tashkeel()`, or do `print strip_tashkeel(text)` directly.

Comment: i tried it ' print strip_tashkeel(text)' but it appears 'ÇáúÚóÑóÈöíøÉõ' :(

Comment: how to make python undersatnd this  'ÇáúÚóÑóÈöíøÉõ' ?

Comment: i think the problem in the shell encoding but how to change the default encoding in windows 7 python2.7?